# Issue Instantiating jQuery jCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I'm having an issue instantiating jCarousel with my new application using jQuery 1.11.2.  I am not using jQuery UI.

Here is the [Website](http://www/davincispainting.com)

I think there is a problem with the call:

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
```

This Carousel was running without problem on previous application using jQuery 1.8.2

I tested the RSS Feed that the Carousel uses, and looks good:
[Blog RSS Feed](http://davincispainting.com/blog/syndication.axd)

Here is the exact code that ran without issue previously:

```
    var mycarousel_itemList = new Array();
    function mycarousel_itemLoadCallback(carousel, state) {
        for (var i = carousel.first; i <= carousel.last; i++) {
            if (carousel.has(i)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (i > mycarousel_itemList.length) {
                break;
            }
            carousel.add(i, mycarousel_getItemHTML(mycarousel_itemList[i - 1]));
        }
    };
    function mycarousel_getItemHTML(item) {
        return '<a href="' + item.url + '">' + item.title + '</a>' + ' ' + item.description.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
    };
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $.get("http://www.davincispainting.com/blog/syndication.axd", function (data) {

            var $xml = $(data);
            $xml.find("item").each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    item = {
                        title: $this.find("title").text(),
                        link: $this.find("link").text(),
                        description: $this.find("description").text()
                    }
                mycarousel_itemList.push({
                    url: item.link,
                    title: item.title,
                    description: item.description
                });
            });
            jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
                vertical: true,
                scroll: 1,
                auto: 1,
                wrap: 'circular',
                size: mycarousel_itemList.length,
                itemLoadCallback: { onBeforeAnimation: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback }
            });
        });
    });



    <div class="col-md-4 boxopacity" style="margin-top: -10px;">
        <div class="headline">
            <h2>Painting Blog & Information</h2>
        </div>
        <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-ie7">
        </ul>
    </div>
```

It would really be helpful if someone could clue me in as to what I'm missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please make sure that the path of "jcarousel.min.js" file is right or not?

It shows me below error.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.davincispainting.com/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"
```

if so then please make correct path for the same. or you can use below path also. Please check this and let us know if you still getting same issue.

```
jquery.jcarousel.js
```

And include one more file after your jquery file

[jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js)

Comment: the jquery.jcarousel.min.js  is now included in the .NET Bundle for Scripts, do you still see that error?

Comment: Yes now more error occur as you include that jcarousel file in bandle. now all the image file are not getting loaded.

Comment: I updated my answer can you please check it and let me know its work for you or not.

Comment: I have jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js  you're saying that this should be included after jquery.jcarousel ?

Comment: No you have to include before it and after jquery-1.11.2.min.js file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79599/discussion-between-ab-vyas-and-paul).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your logs? There are many problems (errors) including the unability to load the jquery.jcarousel.min.js file.

Comment: Chrome Console indicates a TypeError  Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined